# I need to write a program

Tags: c++, c-strings, strlen, function-definition

Task: Write a program that uses a pointer to a character string in a function to determine the number of characters in a string using structures.

The compiler throws an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
    8 |     cout << strlen(a);
      |                    ^
      |                    |
      |                    char
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void func(char a)
{
    cout << strlen(a);

}

int main()
{
    struct student
    {
        char name[64];
    };
    student student1;
    cin >> student1.name;
    char* ptr = &student1.name[64];
    func(*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Либо перепишите вопрос на английском языке, либо удалите его и задайте на ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The `strlen` function requires a `pointer` to a character, not a single character.  Your compiler should give you an error or warning about this.  I recommend you turn your error and warning level to maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several invalid constructions in the program.

You have at least to write instead

```
void func( const char *a )
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
char* ptr = student1.name;
func(ptr);
```

And instead of

```
cin >> student1.name;
```

it is better to use

```
cin.get( student1.name, sizeof( student1.name ) );
```

Also it seems you are not allowed to use the standard C function `strlen` and must write an equivalent function yourself.

Comment: You missed one:  `strlen(a)`, where `a` is of type `char`.  See `void func` in the OP's code. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It does not matter when the function is already declared incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

`char a` is a single character so `strlen(a)` is invalid you need to pass the pointer to func:

```
void func(const char* a)
{
    cout << strlen(a);

}

int main()
{
    struct student
    {
        char name[64];
    };
    student student1;
    cin >> student1.name;
    char* ptr = student1.name;
    func(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I've also changed `&student1.name[64]` as this would get a pointer to the element after the last element in the array which is not what you want.

As we're using c++ we can just use `std::string` to make your code much simpler and safer:

```
void func(const std::string& a)
{
    cout << a.size();

}

int main()
{
    struct student
    {
        std::string name;
    };
    student student1;
    cin >> student1.name;
    func(student1.name);
    return 0;
}
```